# How to retain strings with certain phrases per specific ID?

Tags: r

I have the following example data that contain file paths.

```
paths <- c("data/A101/bill1.xlsx", "data/A101/bill1-separated.xlsx", "data/B215/usage2.csv", "data/B215/usage2-separated.xlsx",
           "data/A101/bill2.xls", "data/A101/bill2-separated.xlsx", "data/C145/account1.xlsx", "data/C145/account1-separated.xlsx",
           "data/A101/bill3.xlsx", "data/B215/usage1.csv", "data/B215/usage3.xls", "data/C145/account2.xlsx") %>% sort()
```

In my data folder, there are subfolders with identifiers for sites. Each subfolder contains data specific to the site. For example, folder `data/A101/` contains 5 data files `bill1-separated.xlsx`, `bill1.xlsx`, `bill2.xls`, `bill2-separated.xlsx`, `bill3.xlsx`.

I want to keep only the file paths with "separated" in the name only if there are a separated version and the original copy. For example, for `bill1-separated.xlsx` and `bill1.xlsx`, I want to keep only the "separated" version.

I want something like this in the end:

```
desired <- c(NA_character_, "data/A101/bill1-separated.xlsx", NA_character_, "data/B215/usage2-separated.xlsx",
             NA_character_, "data/A101/bill2-separated.xlsx", NA_character_, "data/C145/account1-separated.xlsx",
             "data/A101/bill3.xlsx", "data/B215/usage1.csv", "data/B215/usage3.xls", "data/C145/account2.xlsx") %>% sort()
```

My attempt was to use `ifelse` and `grepl` to capture the correct file paths, but I couldn't really get it to work. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
# attempt
temp <- data.frame(path = paths)
temp %>% 
  mutate(
    file = str_extract(paths, "\\/.*\\/(.+)", group=1),
    attempt = ifelse(!grepl("separated", file),
                     NA, # nest another ifelse? but not sure what condition/regex to use
                     path
                     )
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're ignoring file extension, I think we can go with this. (I'm inferring [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) from your code.)

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(
    dir = dirname(path),
    pathnoext = tools::file_path_sans_ext(path),
    notsep = sub("-separated", "", pathnoext)
  ) %>%
  mutate(
    res = if_else(any(grepl("-separated", path)) & pathnoext == notsep, 
                  path[NA], path),
    .by = notsep) %>%
  select(path, res, desire, everything())
#                                 path                               res                            desire       dir                    pathnoext             notsep
# 1               data/A101/bill1.xlsx                              <NA>                              <NA> data/A101              data/A101/bill1    data/A101/bill1
# 2     data/A101/bill1-separated.xlsx    data/A101/bill1-separated.xlsx    data/A101/bill1-separated.xlsx data/A101    data/A101/bill1-separated    data/A101/bill1
# 3               data/B215/usage2.csv                              <NA>                              <NA> data/B215             data/B215/usage2   data/B215/usage2
# 4    data/B215/usage2-separated.xlsx   data/B215/usage2-separated.xlsx   data/B215/usage2-separated.xlsx data/B215   data/B215/usage2-separated   data/B215/usage2
# 5                data/A101/bill2.xls                              <NA>                              <NA> data/A101              data/A101/bill2    data/A101/bill2
# 6     data/A101/bill2-separated.xlsx    data/A101/bill2-separated.xlsx    data/A101/bill2-separated.xlsx data/A101    data/A101/bill2-separated    data/A101/bill2
# 7            data/C145/account1.xlsx                              <NA>                              <NA> data/C145           data/C145/account1 data/C145/account1
# 8  data/C145/account1-separated.xlsx data/C145/account1-separated.xlsx data/C145/account1-separated.xlsx data/C145 data/C145/account1-separated data/C145/account1
# 9               data/A101/bill3.xlsx              data/A101/bill3.xlsx              data/A101/bill3.xlsx data/A101              data/A101/bill3    data/A101/bill3
# 10              data/B215/usage1.csv              data/B215/usage1.csv              data/B215/usage1.csv data/B215             data/B215/usage1   data/B215/usage1
# 11              data/B215/usage3.xls              data/B215/usage3.xls              data/B215/usage3.xls data/B215             data/B215/usage3   data/B215/usage3
# 12           data/C145/account2.xlsx           data/C145/account2.xlsx           data/C145/account2.xlsx data/C145           data/C145/account2 data/C145/account2
```

(Extra columns retained only for demonstration.)

The use of `.by=` requires `dplyr_1.1.0` or newer.

---

Data

```r
df <- structure(list(path = c("data/A101/bill1.xlsx", "data/A101/bill1-separated.xlsx", "data/B215/usage2.csv", "data/B215/usage2-separated.xlsx", "data/A101/bill2.xls", "data/A101/bill2-separated.xlsx", "data/C145/account1.xlsx", "data/C145/account1-separated.xlsx", "data/A101/bill3.xlsx", "data/B215/usage1.csv", "data/B215/usage3.xls", "data/C145/account2.xlsx"), desire = c(NA, "data/A101/bill1-separated.xlsx", NA, "data/B215/usage2-separated.xlsx", NA, "data/A101/bill2-separated.xlsx", NA, "data/C145/account1-separated.xlsx",  "data/A101/bill3.xlsx", "data/B215/usage1.csv", "data/B215/usage3.xls", "data/C145/account2.xlsx")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was trying to understand the code and I have quick question, in `if_else()` in the second `mutate`, what is `path[NA]` exactly doing? Does that only work with the `.by` argument?

Comment: In R, there are over six types of `NA`, and combining them sometimes produces unpredictable results. For instance, `if_else(T, 1, "1")` fails, since it is feasible that our expression could return `numeric` or `character`, depending on if any or all or none of the conditions are true; there are some shortcuts, `if_else(c(T, F), 1, 1L)` works because that is not considered a lossy class-cast. It used to be that `NA` (which is technically `logical`-class) would not be accepted, but a recent change in dplyr fixed that. My habits prevail, though, I'm be explicit and declarative.

Comment: Getting back to `NA`, there are at least six different kinds, including `NA_real_` (numeric), `NA` (logical), `NA_character_`, `NA_complex_`, and some without symbols but still exist (try `identical(NA, Sys.time()[NA])`). It happens to be that when using `[`-indexing, if the index is `NA`, the correct class of the vector is returned, so `""[NA]` is the same as `NA_character_` but shorter. I hope that clears it up.

Comment: (`base::ifelse` is _not_ class-safe. Compare `ifelse(c(T,T), 1, "1")` with `ifelse(c(T,F), 1, "1")` and realize how follow-on unsupervised code might respond when `ifelse` sometimes returns numbers, sometimes return strings.)